# Find all the integral solutions to $2x+3y=200$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

What's the best way of going about this?

> $$2x+3y=200.$$

Comment: You mean "integer"?

Comment: In general adding some context to your question makes these easier to answer. It also makes for more responses as people sometimes ignore questions with zero context or perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case,
if $2x+3y=200$,
an obvious solution is
$x=100, y=0$.

From this base solution,
all other integer solutions are
$x=100-3n$,
$y=2n$
for integer $n$.

If the solutions are to be
non-negative,
then
$n \ge 0$
and
$100-3n \ge 0$,
so
$0 \le n \le \lfloor(100/3)\rfloor 
=33$.

Answer (score 5):

This called a [*Linear Diophantine Equation*](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/number-theory/linear-diophantine/linear-diophantine.html), and the general form is $ax+by=c$. One approach that will solve a variety of equations like this particular one is to note that the $\gcd(2,3)=1$, and applying the [*Euclidean Algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is a general way to do this. In this case, the algorithm takes one line ($3=2 \cdot 1 +1$), and so 
$$3=2 \cdot 1 +1 \Rightarrow 3 \cdot 1 -2 \cdot 1 = 1 \Rightarrow 2(-1)+3 (1)=1.$$
Now multiplying across by 200 gives one integral solution, namely
$$2(-200)+3 (200)=200.$$
To find all integral solutions, where $x_0=-200$, $y_0=200$, $d=\gcd(2,3)$, $a=2$, and $b=3$, we can just write
$$x=\frac{b}{d}n+x_0=3n-200, \,\, y=-\frac{a}{d}n+y_0=-2n+200, \,\, n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

The links above should help you with solving this class of equations and provide greater explanation. I hate posting formulas with no derivation, but such derivations exceed the scope of your question, and are readily available on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

$2\,|\,y$. $\quad x + 3\,{y \over 2} = 100$.
$\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad x_{n} = 100 - 3n.\quad n = 0,1,2,\ldots,33}$.

$$
200 - 6n + 3y_{n} = 200\,,
\quad
\color{#ff0000}{\large y_{n} = 2n} 
$$

$$
\left(100,0\right),\left(97,2\right),\left(94,4\right),\left(91,6\right),\ldots
$$